# How to add pages like about,DCMA... in bottom of the Blogspot?

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, themes, blogger

Like the screenshot from wordpress

[image: xxx enter image description here xxx]

how to do that in Blogspot.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to do.

1. Go to 'Pages' and create the pages you want.
2. Use the code below and paste your page links here: `<a href="ADD LINK HERE"`

You can either add this in the HTML somewhere closely above `</body>` or go into 'Layout', go to the the footer section, add a HTML/Javascript widget and paste this. Then just edit it. If you plan on changing your template, go with the latter route.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="">Change Me</a> | <a href="">Change Me</a> | <a href="">Change Me</a> | <a href="">Change Me</a> | <a href="">Change Me</a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"> 2015-<script type="text/javascript">var creditsyear = new Date();document.write(creditsyear.getFullYear());</script>
© All Rights Reserved</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to 'Pages' and create the pages you want.
2. Then go to 'layout' secton and go to footer and click 'add gadgets '
3. Click 'link list from the menu
4. Below you will find 'add a new item
5. All the page title and it's link below.

You are done!
Hope it's helpful!